# adding an attachment to an html email form sent with .asp

Tags: asp-classic, email-attachments

I have just taken over looking after a website. The owner has asked if i can add the facility for the user to attach a file via the contact us html email form. The email form is sent via a .asp file.

I don't know anything about .asp but have researched as much as i can and still am lost. I know i can add a file upload button to the form that will send a file to a folder on the server, but am unsure if any other code is required in the form?

This is a sample of the code in the .asp file and i wondered if i could simply add some code to this as i know it currently works or would i need to replace it?

Revised html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload test" action="test_sendMail.asp">
<p><input type="file" name="upload" size="20"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use the built-in CDO Mail ?

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.AddAttachment Server.MapPath("..\mydocuments\attachment.txt")
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

Comment: I have been unable to make this work, could someone offer me guidance on what the html for the form would be and if there is anything else to add to the CDO code kindly submitted?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you have tried in your original question, and what did not work ? Please check out the following link : http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp . It might be so that you need to use that last manner. CDO.Message SHOULD definitely work on an ASP webserver.

Comment: I've tried to do a very basic test - see revised html above, using this cdo test you offered but i didn't know what should be in the brackets after server.mapath so i left it blank ecept for the quote marks. I published it and tested it and i didn't get any error messages, it seemed as though it sent, but of course i never received the email. Sorry, i am out of my depth with this. The host company tell me there are no issues at their end. Thank you